# Installing Rake: invalid gem format

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, rake

I installed Ruby on WinXP. Used rubyinstaller-1.8.6-p383-rc1.exe.

Ran `gem install rake`

Get error:

> Error installing rake: invalid gem format for C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem

I've tried deleting the cache folder but i keep getting the same error. Tried with Ruby 1.9.1 too. Same error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I voted to close this. Now asking on superuser.com:
http://superuser.com/questions/81429/installing-rake-invalid-gem-format